# Error, exception in kayako library when uploading file

Tags: php, file, exception, upload

when I upload a file larger than 1mb, any size below 1mb works fine, this is the error i get error:

> Uncaught exception 'kyException' with message 'HTTP error: 400' in
>   /./public_html./kyRESTClient.php:187 Stack trace: #0
>   /./././kyRESTClient.php(224):
>   kyRESTClient->processRequest('/Tickets/Ticket...', 'POST', Array,
>   Array, Array) #1 /././././kyObjectBase.php(328):
>   kyRESTClient->post('/Tickets/Ticket...', Array, Array) #2
>   /././iniciar_ticke.php(241): kyObjectBase->create() #3 {main} thrown
>   in /./././kyRESTClient.php on line 187

Comment: I can't clean up the error, but have put the content into better English, so should help a little

Comment: thanks, please helpme